# Force HTTPS for a certain url in htaccess (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have this code in my *htaccess:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/login [NC]
RewriteRule ^(login) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/login [NC]
RewriteRule !^login http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

It forces my `/login` to HTTPS instead of HTTP but the thing is, it gives me an error when I access the `/login`. Error is

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this redirect instead - you have to put in the absolute URL which is not ideal but on the plus side it should do what you need with 1 line

```
RewriteRule ^login$ https://yourdomain.com/login [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I only like to https a certain url (/login)